# All the examples of WebRTC are video chat, is it possible to send any type of video over WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

So I want to be able to send a normal video from a video file (AVI or any other) through WebRTC, can that be done? The only examples I see of WebRTC are video chats, so I feel as if its only geared towards webcam and chats.

So my question is, technically can sending normal video from a video file (not webcam) over WebRTC be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try: "[**Pre-recorded media streaming**](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/)" --- [Documentation and Source Code](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming).

This experiment uses **MediaSource API** to render **Blobs** in `<video>` element. This experiment has some issues need to be fixed e.g. it can't send longer **WebM** videos.

---

You can try [this experiment](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/index-2.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The codecs typically used in AVI are not directly supported by WebRTC clients, but if you are writing your own standalone client then of course it could read an AVI or other video file and transcode it to VP8 video and Opus audio (or whatever other codecs you were able to negotiate), and transmit it via RTP.  If you are trying to do video transcoding in JavaScript in a browser then that will be very slow.